# Will a 3D printed ESD dissipative housing prevent spark travelling through air hole to PCB?

Tags: emc, esd

I have little clearance between my PCB and the air holes of its plastic housing, meaning an air discharge is able to conduct to the PCB through the hole. If I make the housing out of an ESD dissipative material will the spark discharge to this first as the ESD gun approaches, or will the housing's resistance be too high?

I am considering dissipative plastics such as [ABS-ESD7](https://www.stratasys.com/materials/search/abs-esd7)

Comment: the path of least resistance; what's the housing made of?

Comment: just as a warning, the term "esd dissipative material" is sometimes used to describe plastics, which are resistant to buildup of static charge -- rather than being as conductive as a metal. // even if it were metal, the answer depends on the details of the geometry, and effective grounding

Comment: @PeteW The OP's material is not such a mateiral though as per the linked data. It truly is a dissipative material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing with a few materials and an ESD gun, shown here is for conductive foam. (I also did conductive plastic, not shown)

[image]

The spark would find the nearest "conductive material". An interesting result was if a conductive aluminum plate was placed next conductive plastic, the spark actually preferred the plastic (the were almost identical heights.)

At the end of the day how conductive a material is doesn't matter much to a kV voltage, because once you start a plasma and breakdown occurs everything get's more conductive.

The conductive ABS-ESD7 has a volume resistivity of at least 10^4 Ω (highest being 10^9 Ω)

I have an ESD bench that has 10^9 Ω and sparks dissipate into that just fine, so at the end of the day I think you'll be fine. Any ESD events should dissipate in the plastic (as long as it is connected to a ground to return the transient voltage to the source).

Oh, and remember that air is Giga to terra ohms so to a kV source anything looks conductive to a source like that.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you for taking the time to experiment! Good to know you are able to ignite sparks to your ESD bench also, 10^9 Ω means [ESD spray paint](https://uk.farnell.com/techspray/1756-8s/static-dissipative-coating-8-oz/dp/2501345) is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

Air holes will be problematic being the lowest capacitance and thus highest conductance to transient voltage breakdown.   A Mylar shield that still permits air flow  would be best to any exposed conductors.

I recall tiny gaps around LED indicators on recessed 5mm LEDs with 10 mm high lens on early 80’s keyboards would often fail ESD tests with a Schaefer ESD gun @ 10kV travelling 10mm or so.